# Angular 6 time picker seems to cut off end of MM display

Tags: angular, html, datetimepicker

In all browsers the minutes in the timepicker are cut off as shown in the image, is there any way to rectify this? I can't see anything obvious.  The class 'timeColor' is only setting the colour.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 center-datepicker"><input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="eventDetail.StartDateTime" id="startDate" name="startDate" [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD MMMM YYYY'}" #startDate="ngModel" autocomplete="off"/></div>
    <div class="col-2"><timepicker [(ngModel)]="eventDetail.StartDateTime" id="startTime" name="startTime" class="timeColor" #startTime="ngModel" (isValid)="isStartTimeValid($event, startTime, endTime)"></timepicker></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could use HTML to write Xamarin.  If this is the case your tags are wrong and should say html and not xaml.

Comment: sorry, working on about 3 different things here! will change it

Comment: lol, makes more sense now.  I was looking to see if you could actually use html in xamarin because I know there was or still is an html version of UWP.

Comment: can you change the padding of the input box?

Comment: no difference I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone looking for an answer to this, I got it by adding the following to the component css file

```
:host ::ng-deep #startTime input{
    width: 80px;
}
```

This increased the width of the input boxes within the timepicker without affecting the other inputs on the page